# Compare two objects, excluding one property from the comparison

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, chai

I have an object:

```
var object_1 = {
     random_id: 'random_id_1';
     name: name;
     surname: surname;
}
```

and

```
var object_2 = {
     random_id: 'random_id_2';
     name: 'name';
     surname: 'surname';
}
```

How can I compare these two objects but excluding `random_id`

I tried to use the `chai-exclude` plugin:

```
expect(object_1).excluding('random_id').to.deep.equal(object_2)
```

but without success.

Answer (score 3):

The way to add chai-exclude is

```js
import chaiExclude from 'chai-exclude';
chai.use(chaiExclude);

var object1 = {
  random_id: 'random_id_1',
  name: 'name',
  surname: 'surname'
}

var object2 = {
  random_id: 'random_id_2',
  name: 'name',
  surname: 'surname'
}

expect(object_1).excluding('random_id').to.deep.equal(object_2)
```

---

You can instead use `Cypress._.omit()`

```js
expect(Cypress._.omit(object_1, ['random_id']))
  .to.deep.equal(Cypress._.omit(object_2, ['random_id']))
```

---

Or with destructing

```js
let {random_id, ...obj1} = object_1
cy.then(() => {
  let {random_id, ...obj2} = object_2
  expect(obj1).to.deep.eq(obj2)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Chai in the callback functions for Cypress.

```js
var object_1 = {
     random_id: 'random_id_1';
     name: name;
     surname: surname;
}

var object_2 = {
     random_id: 'random_id_2';
     name: 'name';
     surname: 'surname';
}

cy.wrap(object_1).should((object1) => {
  expect(object1).excluding('random_id').to.deep.equal(object_2);
});
```

[Have you installed the `chai-exclude` library](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-exclude/) and configured it correctly?